# SQL Server Merge - Getting matched records to another temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a `MERGE` query to update data. In case of no match I am inserting records to source getting the output to a temporary table.

Would it be possible to get the matched records to temporary table as well? Basically to avoid duplication of data in further processing I need to have copy of matched records.

This is my `MERGE` command:

```
MERGE Product.ProductHeaderRepository AS t 
USING (SELECT GETDATE() as d, c1, c2, c3,
Name FROM Supplier.ProductHeaderImport
WHERE (BatchID = @BatchID) ) AS s
ON dbo.GetProductHeaderId(s.c1,S.c2,S.c3) <0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (Name, c1,c2,c3) VALUES (Name, c2,c2,c3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.iD, s.c1, s.c2, s.c3 INTO @TmpTable;
```

Comment: Try adding `$action` to your `OUTPUT` and temporary table. I think it's already doing what you want.

Answer (score 13):

You could create a `MATCHED` clause that does not change anything and just updates a variable, e.g.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (A INT, B INT);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (A INT, B INT);
DECLARE @T3 TABLE (Action VARCHAR(20), A INT, B INT);

INSERT @T1 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);
INSERT @T2 VALUES (1, 0), (2, NULL), (4, 0);

DECLARE @I INT; -- VARIABLE TO UPDATE

MERGE @T2 B
USING @T1 A
    ON A.A = B.A
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET @I = 1   -- DO NOTHING MEANINGFUL IN THE UPDATE;
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (A, B) VALUES (A.A, A.B)
OUTPUT $action, ISNULL(inserted.A, deleted.A), ISNULL(inserted.B, deleted.B) INTO @T3;

SELECT  *
FROM    @T3;
```

Will return:

```
Action  A   B
INSERT  3   3
UPDATE  1   0
UPDATE  2   NULL
```

So if you add a new column to `@TmpTable` to store the action you can get your matched rows using:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @TmpTable
WHERE   Action = 'UPDATE';
```

And your new rows using:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @TmpTable
WHERE   Action = 'INSERT';
```

Comment: Note that the join conditions must be in parentheses `ON()`

Comment: @benrhoumamoez This is not true at all. The question contains a full example that works fine without parenthesis.